# windowSoftInputMode does not pan Window

Tags: java, android, material-design

I don't know how to get my soft keyboard to show up under an TextView Field. It just covers up my Button and TextView.

I have used this link http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html
as a reference. But it isn't working.

I have  `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the *AndroidManifest* file for my activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".SearchView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_view"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.txisystems.inventory.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Here is what the screen looks like without the soft keyboard.

[image]

and the code to go with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.inventory.SearchView"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search_view">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mylogo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearchField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        android:maxLength="17"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:capitalize="none" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearchField"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:onClick="doSearch"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="@color/buttontext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSearchMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Please enter 4 or more characters."
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/error"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what happens (I used Photoshop to simulate the screen.) 
The keyboard can't be dismissed and it covers the button and the message area.

[image]

And here is what I want to happen through the magic of Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: adjustPan is for scrolling views. You may want to use adjustResize

Comment: adjustResize causes the text field to squish the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the Activity (OnCreate) which hosts the XML:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```